# Parse facebook signed request in a drupal modules

Tags: drupal, facebook-graph-api, drupal-modules

A simple question,

Can i parse the facebook signed_request inside a drupal module? In order to get user's information? without authentication of any kind?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you *can* parse it (once you’ve got hold of it) – but it won’t give you much info regarding the user besides their Facebook uid.

Once the user is *connected* to your app, you can query some of their data making a Graph API call for /me – no *extra* permissions besides basic permissions required.

(For parsing it, see Facebook docs on signed_request; or just embed the PHP SDK, which already offers a method to do it.)

Comment: let me ask this thing please, to be more specific, what i need to know is just if this is doable, 
I have a drupal website, which i need to load inside a facebook page tab, i need to create a module in drupal which takes the signed request as a variable and it parses it, so if a user visits the tab , if he likes a certain page he will be redirected tn't then he will be redirected to another facebook page.

but in which page he will be redirected i need to choose it within that module.. can i do that?

Comment: You gave me the worst news possible :P, thanks anyways! i appreciate your help!